# G++ to Matlab serial only reading first message

Tags: c++, matlab, serialization, g++

I am doing a software in loop test of a flight control system I am building. I am using G++ gnu to process flight information fed to it by a Matlab simulation of the aircraft.

To get Matlab and g++ to talk to each other, I am using a virtual serial port (connecting two non-physical COM ports). Thus, I am using serial communication to send the data between them (COM5 is virtually connected to COM6 via the [Virtual Serial Port Driver](https://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp/)).

This gets us to the problem: Matlab will only read the first message sent from G++, and any remaining messages will return empty.

**Table of Contents of Code:**

1. **Open Serial Port (on G++ side)**
2. **Send Message and Send Stop (on G++ side)**
3. **Example G++ Code that Displays My Issue**
4. **Example Matlab Receiving Code that Displays My Issue**

Open Serial Port (on G++ side)

```
class SerialPort
{
    HANDLE hCom;
    public:
    SerialPort(char * comportname);
    ClosePort();
    void send(void *buffer, int num_bytes);
    void sendstop(SerialPort sport);
    int readline(unsigned char *buffer);
};

SerialPort::SerialPort(char * comportname)
{
    // set up the serial port
    hCom = CreateFileA(comportname,GENERIC_READ | 
    GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) printf("\n*** CreateFile failed with error : %d\n", GetLastError());
    DCB dcb;
    BOOL fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;    // 115200 baud rate
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // 8 bits data
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;        // no parity bit
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // one stop bit
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE; // no flow control
    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
    if(!fSuccess) printf("\n*** SetCommState failed with error : %d\n", GetLastError());
    fSuccess = SetCommMask(hCom, EV_TXEMPTY | EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR);
    if(!fSuccess) printf("\n*** SetCommMask failed with error : %d\n", GetLastError());

    COMMTIMEOUTS cto_time;
    GetCommTimeouts(hCom, &cto_time);
    cto_time.ReadIntervalTimeout = 100; // set time-out to 100 milliseconds
    SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &cto_time);
}
```

2. **Send Message and Send Stop (on G++ side)**

```
void SerialPort::send(void *buffer, int num_bytes)
{
    DWORD dwWriteCount;
    WriteFile(hCom, buffer, num_bytes, &dwWriteCount, NULL);
}
void SerialPort::sendstop(SerialPort sport){
    int STOPBIT[]={9};//stop bit
    sport.send(STOPBIT,sizeof(STOPBIT));
}
```

3. **Example G++ Code that Displays My Issue**

```
#define S_PORT "COM5"
#include "serialport.cpp"//see #1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char serialportname[] = S_PORT; // the serial port to read/write from
SerialPort sp(serialportname);
printf("Waiting for first message from matlab...\n");
char received_string[32];
printf("~:"); sp.readline((unsigned char *)received_string); 
printf("%s\n",received_string);printf("\n");

int main(void){
    unsigned char rep1[]="Hello Plant"; 
    sp.send(rep1,sizeof(rep1));
    sp.sendstop(sp);

    unsigned char rep2[]="Start";
    sp.send(rep2,sizeof(rep2));//This is where the error starts, it cant read the second message
    sp.sendstop(sp);
    return 0;
}
```

4. **Example Matlab Receiving Code that Displays My Issue**

```
s=serial('COM6');
s.Baudrate=115200;
s.StopBits=1;
s.Terminator=9;
fopen(s);
fwrite(s,'Hello Processor');
fwrite(s,'8');%stopbit for Matlab is 9(Tab in ASCII), and GNU side's is 8(Backspace in ASCII)

rep = fgets(s);
rep %displaying

rep2 = fgets(s);%this fails to read "Start" and gets an empty ''
rep2 %displaying
fclose(s);
```

**My theory** is that it is somehow only reading the start bit, or reading only some of the information that came over the serial, or perhaps the start bit is not being read properly.

**What I have already tried**

-Altering delays in an attempt to solve any possible synchronization problems

-Opening and closing the serial port after every message

-Writing longer messages to see if it is reading the wrong section

-Changing the stop bit

**Note that these attempts could still tell us about the problem, I just didn't see any information from them**

**Other Forum Post(s) On This Subject** (that didn't really help)
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/17004-cannot-read-from-com-port-more-than-once
[Matlab serial read bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875543/matlab-serial-read-bug)

If anyone could tell me what I am missing, I would be ***immensely*** grateful.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting, I found a process that seems to make it work always.

To send it properly, one needs to:

1. Get the data via fgetl or fscanf or fgets.
2. Use flushinput(serialportobject) (to clear the buffer?)
3. Before sending the next message, the TX side has to sleep for a certain amount of time (for me it was 13 milliseconds);

Sample Script (using code from original post):

Tx side:

```
char rep1[]="hello";
sp.send(rep1, sizeof(rep1));
sp.sendstop(sp);
Sleep(13); //Important for next read
```

Rx side:

```
rep=fscanf(s);
flushinput(s);
//Next read can go here
```